# How to get serial number of iPad in ios8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, udid, iokit

In my app I am getting serial number of the device using IOKit framework. This is working fine in ios7. In IOS8 it is giving null. Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Other than Serial Number & UDID is there anything else which is unique for iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Apple deprecated access to a unique-per-device UUID and other sorts of unique identifiers. [Check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW34). But maybe this could help you:

On `UIDevice` there's `identifierForVendor`, that is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device and is different for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor. Apps that need an identifier for their own advertising purposes should consider using the `advertisingIdentifier` property of `ASIdentifierManager` instead.

Framework called `AdSupport`, that provides apps with access to an identifier that can be used only for serving advertisements

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/index.html) is another link that maybe helps you

Comment: Hi mauricioconde thanks for your quick response.Can you please confirm is there any way to get serial number programatically or not.

Comment: None that Apple has made public, no. If you do find a way then your code will probably never be approved for the App Store, so if the App Store is your goal then you would be wiser spending your energy finding another way to do what you're trying to do than with the serial number.

Comment: Hi jef is there any other number (except serial number and UDID) which is unique for the device(iPad/iphone).Please let me know it will helps me a lot.

Comment: As jef has mentioned, its no longer possible to identify a device like that. So no serial numbers or MAC addresses etc. You can use identifierForVendor or find another way.